# Understanding a prometheus query for memory free (node-exporter)

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

can anyone help me understand a query from prometheus with data from node-exporter?

I have taken a query from the community, it is the following - notice the "1 -" in front of the full query. This is the query I obtained.

```
(1 - (node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{node_type=~"mining"} / (node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{node_type=~"mining"})))* 100 > 75
```

I don't understand why the "1-" is there. This particular query right now returns 2 results.

I removed the "1-" like so

```
(node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes{node_type=~"mining"} / (node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{node_type=~"mining"}))* 100 > 75
```

Now the query returns 4 results.

I am a little confused at which is correct and why would the "1-" be before the query.

Here is a screenshot showing the prometheus query results

Could anybody help or explain and maybe I am missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct is the first (with the "1-"), the "mathmagic" is explained following.

We have:

```
MemUsed = MemTotal - MemAvailable
```

So:

```
% MemUsed = ((MemTotal - MemAvailble) / MemTotal) * 100
```

Simplifying we have:

```
% MemUsed = (MemTotal / MemTotal - MemAvailable / MemTotal) * 100
```

And finally:

```
% MemUsed = (1 - MemAvailable / MemTotal) * 100
```

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thanks.